# Calculating number of AES encryption/sec

Tags: encryption, aes

How fast in terms of the number  AES encryption/sec, would an Internet encryptor need to be if the plain text rate is 10gb/sec?

Comment: Maybe this question should be asked on https://security.stackexchange.com or https://crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not sure what "AES encryption/sec" is. But since encryption does not change the number of bytes ther answer would be 10gb/sec.

Comment: @Palna Patel You can edit the question to make it more clear, example scenarios would help.

Answer (score 0):

AES encrypts 16 bytes per operation (block). You can do the math :)

BTW: for a 10gbit connection to be saturated you‘ll have to do some serious engineering.